# How to insert NULL into a datetime in python with pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, null, pymysql

I'm trying to insert some `datetime`  in `My-SQL` database in an SQL da on python with `pymysql` but sometimes those dates that , I retrieve are Nonetype, I want to insert a date to null when this happen, What should i do ?

I tried what i seen on stackoverflow, nothing worked,`"", 0, "NULL",` ternary conditions inserting None ...

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item[3]) if type(item[3][3])` is not None else None

Every time the same Error

```html
"""INSERT INTO database (atr1, atr2, atr3, 
            atr4, atr5, atr6, atr7, atr8, atr9)
            VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')""" % (item[0], item[1],\
            item[2], datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item[3]),\
            datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item[4]), item[5],\
            item[6], item[9],time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))


    item[2],datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item[3]),\
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType)
```

Thanks for your help!